# Scala exception: value registerTempTable is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I have copied the below code from 
http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.0/sql-programming-guide.html

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext._
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
val people = sc.textFile("/home/rawTbl.tsv").map(_.split(",")).map(p => Person(p(0), p(1).trim.toInt))
people.registerAsTable("people")
```

However, it throws an exception shown below

```
"value registerTempTable is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD"
```

I am using Spark Version 1.3.0

Pleases suggest some solution to fix this issue.

Comment: Read the official doc for Spark 1.3 if you are using 1.3!

Answer (score 0):

You need to register it as a temp table first before you try to save it.
people.registerTempTable ("people")
Should work.

Comment: I tried the same, however still got the same exception
 error: value registerTempTable is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
 When I search stuff available for people, I got below results. 
 scala> people.r
 randomSplit   reduce        repartition

Comment: registerTempTable  is a method on DataFrame, not SchemaRDD